# how to connect android usb device in pc after installing Google USB driver

Tags: android

I have installed Google USB driver by using SDK manager and debugging mode in on in my phone. But when I connect android phone to my pc ,I see USB is connected but when I want to run application to device ,it says no compatible device is found. what should do I know? Anybody help me, please.

Comment: `adb kill-server`.`adb start-server`.`adb devices`

Comment: @ Ahmad please show me how write it  in command prompt in windows 8

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have enabled usb debugging on the device you have connected.